# Trouble installing mediapipe package on pycharm mac

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, mediapipe

I need to use the mediapipe package along with opencv for tracking hand movement, i have tried to install it through the interpreter settings in pycharm but it comes up with the message:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe

I have tried to upgrade macOS to the newest version, upgraded pip to the newest version, but it doesn't help with the problem.

Comment: ARM based? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68659865/cannot-pip-install-mediapipe-on-macos-m1 There's some GitHub issue too, https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/3277

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.